# DNN API Role based authorization

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dotnetnuke, role-base-authorization

I want to apply authorization on API call with respect to DNN roles. so that DNN itself will perform checks whether logged user has access to particular API call. I got one solution but not exactly what I want. = > [How to handle security/authentication on a DNN-based web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16044985/how-to-handle-security-authentication-on-a-dnn-based-web-api). This link suggest to have separate module for API authorization so that we can assign roles to this module and by using [SupportedModules("ModuleName")] attribute on API call we can restrict authorization. I checked this example but no luck...PLZ suggest me proper way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

As long as you work with the DnnApiController as part of 7.x you can simply add this attribute to any method to require authorization based on role.

```
[DnnAuthorize(StaticRoles = "MyRoleNameHere")]
```

Where "MyRoleNameHere" is the name of the role that the user must have.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but with this solution I may not be able to change roles dynamically. Ex. If I want to change roles or add new roles to access the API then I need to change the code by updating StaticRoles values.

Comment: @Mitchel Sellers, to allow access to multiple roles, just delimit by commas?

Comment: Hey sorry for asking, but how can I put more than one role name there?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the delayed response. Comma separated seems to work for this

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked this post?
http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Blogs/EntryId/3329/Authorization-in-the-new-DNN-Services-Framework.aspx

I have found this useful (as well as the other answer you referred to)... but it's taken me a long time to understand it! Here's what I've figured out so far:
If you're using a web browser, DNN can accept your request and evaluate the permissions (based on your login). The linked blog entry demonstrates this with an API that lists tabs -- it only shows the tabs your login has permission to see. If you write an HTTP request from somewhere else (such as in a PHP script), you can see the same behavior if you send username/password with the request.

You can use the DnnAuthorize attribute, but using role names directly can be problematic for the reasons you mentioned -- what if they change? However, you can write your own attribute. Basically, it will require (in some way, shape, or form) a TabID and ModuleID. That way, instead of checking a role name, you can have DNN check what permissions the current user has for that module.

You can write a module for it, assign role-based permissions to your module, and have DNN just check that tab/module for the given login. Writing your own attribute will make it easy to assign the permissions in your controller... without specifying the roles directly.

I believe the link refers to DNN 6.2, so there may be some differences with 7.

Comment: To solve my problem for some extent I did the following.
1. I created one module only for setting roles to access the APIs
2. Then I added the same module id in appSetting in webconfig file to know this module has to be used for authorization.
3. Then I wrote my own Authorize attribute in which I did comparison for logged users roles with the roles which has been assigned to modules.

Comment: Thanks to all for helping...! whats your suggestion for my answer.