# Converting WCF to WEB API : Is it a good idea to reuse the WCF services with a wrapper in WEB API

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, wcf-rest

I want to migrate from my wcf rest services to web api. Is it a good idea to have wrapper services, i.e. to call WCF services from the API endpoints? Please suggest.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If your services have no WCF specific code and contain only business logic, then it would be a good idea. Your WEB API Controllers would be only the wrappers, that handle basically routing, arguments mapping and returning HTTP status code with appropriate result.

**EDIT:**

If your WCF services have some WCF specific code, like authentication, then I suggest extracting the code that is infrastructure independent. Then you'll be able to use those new extracted classes from your WEB API controllers.

In case of such massive refactoring, I usually recommend covering the whole component with integration or end-to-end tests. The tests can be written on top of existing code and infrastructure. After extracting the code and wrapping it with WEB API controllers, you'll be able to run the same tests suite to make sure there are no breaking changes.

Regarding authentication in WEB API, I suggest looking at the following SO: [Web API Authentication best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12222527/web-api-authentication-best-practice)

Comment: WCF rest services have its own logic.
In Wcf services, I have a class inherited from 'ServiceAuthorizationManager' and the below logic to do the authentication.

var reqMsgProp = (HttpRequestMessageProperty)operationContext.IncomingMessageProperties["httpRequst"];

string authHeader =

reqMsgProp.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization];

var authMessage = CheckIfAuthenticateMethod(operationContext);

if (authMessage == true)

{

return true;

}

In WEB API 2 architecture, I'm using token based authentication. So how can I do the authentication part?